# Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element (:root { ... --font-size-tiny: ... }), in atrule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

In my rails app I get this warning from webpacker-dev-server:

```
Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element (:root { ... --font-size-tiny: ... }), in atrule
```

And many more for further custom properties.
In consequence I get warnings when the properties are used:

```
variable '--font-size-tiny' is undefined and used without a fallback
```

css is as follows:

```
:root {
  --font-size-tiny: 0.8125rem;
  --line-height-tiny: 1rem;
  ...
}

@media screen and (min-width:26.5625rem) {
  :root {
    --font-size-tiny: calc(0.8125rem + 0 * (100vw - 26.5625rem) / 21.4375);
    --line-height-tiny: calc(1rem + 0 * (100vw - 26.5625rem) / 21.4375);
    ...
  }
}
```

I do not understand this warning, because the properties are explicitly scoped to :root.

What I tried:

- Changing :root to html. Same problem with same warnings.
- Building a simple Hello World app with rails and webpacker. I thought that maybe webpacker has an issue with custom properties. But no problem, the Hello World app handles fine with custom properties scoped to :root.

I don't want to suppress these warnings like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49629759/7996789), because they lead to a warning which in fact is an error when the properties are used.

Does anyone have an idea?